# TSQL Convert FLOAT to STRING Truncation/Rounding Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, type-conversion, floating-point

SQL Server 2008 R2

Why when converting a `FLOAT` to a string (`Varchar` / `Nvarchar`) using `Cast` or `Convert`, does a rounding or truncation occur?

Using `CAST`

```
DECLARE @floatVal FLOAT = 4.76758527755737

SELECT
    CAST(@floatVal AS VARCHAR(20)) 'VARCHAR',
    CAST(@floatVal AS NVARCHAR(20)) 'NVARCHAR'
```

Output

```
VARCHAR NVARCHAR
4.76759 4.76759
```

Using `CONVERT`:

```
DECLARE @floatVal FLOAT = 4.76758527755737

SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @floatVal) 'VARCHAR',
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @floatVal) 'NVARCHAR'
```

Output

```
VARCHAR NVARCHAR
4.76759 4.76759
```

With `STR` however, there's no truncation/rounding

```
DECLARE @floatVal FLOAT = 4.76758527755737

SELECT
    LTRIM(STR(@floatVal, 17, 14)) 'STR'
```

Output

```
STR
4.76758527755737
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation about [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

[image]

`CAST` is 'apparently' using the default *style* of 0 since you cannot specify a style when using `CAST`.

`CONVERT` defaulted to *style* 0 since you did not specify a *style*.

You can achieve more precision using `CONVERT` and *style* (and your have to increase the length of the target datatype), but the results appear to be in scientific notation (so, not exactly like `STR`).

```
DECLARE @floatVal   FLOAT = 4.76758527755737

SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @floatVal,1)     'VARCHAR'
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @floatVal,1)   'NVARCHAR'
GO
```

[image]